# How can I get CPU overall usage and individual core usage information just once?

Tags: top, cpu-usage

Is there a command which can show CPU usage information (both for overall cpu and for individual cores), in a static way (i.e. just once) similar to how `free` shows memory usage information?

When we run `top`, the cpu information at the top part after hitting `1` to show individual core usage as well as overall cpu usage may be what I want. But `top`   by default dynamically update the information, and output more information (memory and per process information) than I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a command to show processor related runtime statistics on the fly, called 
`mpstat`. On most distributions it is part of the `sysstat` package.

Whilst it has an output that could be a more direct answer to your question `mpstat -P ALL -I CPU`, I prefer the output of `mpstat -P ALL`, which is **much more intelligible**.

As an example, the output in a machine with 40 CPUs:

```
Linux 3.0.101-63-default    02/16/19    _x86_64_

09:52:11     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
09:52:11     all    0.04    0.00    0.04    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.90
09:52:11       0    0.13    0.00    0.13    0.57    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.16
09:52:11       1    0.24    0.00    0.49    0.07    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.21
09:52:11       2    0.04    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.94
09:52:11       3    0.03    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.95
09:52:11       4    0.02    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.97
09:52:11       5    0.02    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11       6    0.02    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.98
09:52:11       7    0.02    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.97
09:52:11       8    0.01    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.98
09:52:11       9    0.01    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.98
09:52:11      10    0.12    0.00    0.10    0.19    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.59
09:52:11      11    0.09    0.00    0.06    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.84
09:52:11      12    0.03    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.94
09:52:11      13    0.03    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.94
09:52:11      14    0.03    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.95
09:52:11      15    0.03    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.95
09:52:11      16    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.95
09:52:11      17    0.03    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.95
09:52:11      18    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      19    0.03    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.95
09:52:11      20    0.06    0.00    0.06    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.87
09:52:11      21    0.19    0.00    0.27    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.54
09:52:11      22    0.02    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.97
09:52:11      23    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      24    0.02    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.97
09:52:11      25    0.02    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.97
09:52:11      26    0.01    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.98
09:52:11      27    0.01    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.98
09:52:11      28    0.01    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.98
09:52:11      29    0.01    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.98
09:52:11      30    0.04    0.00    0.04    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.92
09:52:11      31    0.03    0.00    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.94
09:52:11      32    0.02    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      33    0.02    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      34    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      35    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      36    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      37    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      38    0.02    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
09:52:11      39    0.03    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.96
```

From `man mpstat`

> The  mpstat  command writes to standard output activities for each available processor, processor 0 being the first one.  Global
>   average activities among all proces-sors are also reported.  The
>   mpstat command can be used both on SMP and UP machines, but in the
>   latter, only global average activities will be printed. If no 
>   activity has been selected, then the default report is the CPU
>   utilization report.

If you are interested on the topic, I recommend the book:

[Systems Performance: Enterprise and the Cloud, Brendan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/sysperfbook.html)

PS Whilst `mpstat` is quite useful for the short term, the companion `sar` utility that also gets installed with `sysstat`, ends up being more useful, for establishing patterns and a baseline over the long term.

*corollary*: Don't go `cron` with `mpstat`, use `sar`.

Comment: `mpstat -P ALL` must be the stats averaged since boot? It seems to output the same exact numbers every time I run it, so I must assume so.

Answer (score 2):

```
top -bn 1
```

After you set up your top rc;

```
top
1
W
q
```

grep what you want

```
top -bn 1 | grep -P "^(%|top)"
```

For output like

```
top - 11:40:33 up 24 days, 32 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
 %Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  1.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.1 id,  0.1 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.9 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu4  :  2.0 us,  2.0 sy,  0.2 ni, 93.0 id,  2.3 wa,  0.2 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu5  :  0.9 us,  3.0 sy,  0.1 ni, 94.8 id,  0.8 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu6  :  0.2 us,  2.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.4 id,  0.4 wa,  0.2 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
 %Cpu7  :  0.1 us,  1.0 sy,  0.1 ni, 98.4 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) How can I just get the CPU usage part, not memory part, not per process part? (2) can I also get both per core usage part, and overall cpu usage part?

Comment: Thanks.  On Lubuntu 18.04, `top -bn 1` doesn't show individual cores

Comment: @Tim then you missed the '1 W' part.