# How to get overall CPU usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I am wondering how you can get the system CPU usage and present it in percent using bash, for example.

Sample output:

```
57%
```

In case there is more than one core, it would be nice if an average percentage could be calculated.

Comment: Related: [How can I get CPU overall usage and individual core usage information just once?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501004/how-can-i-get-cpu-overall-usage-and-individual-core-usage-information-just-once)

Comment: See also: [How to get overall CPU usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to **see the overall CPU usage**. This calls `python3` and uses the cross-platform [`psutil` module](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/).

```bsh
printf "%b" "import psutil\nprint('{}%'.format(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)))" | python3
```

The `interval=2` part says to measure the total CPU load over a blocking period of 2 seconds.

Sample output:

```
9.4%
```

The python program it contains is this:

```py
import psutil

print('{}%'.format(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)))
```

Placing `time` in front of the call proves it takes the specified interval time of about 2 seconds in this case. Here is the call and output:

```bsh
$ time printf "%b" "import psutil\nprint('{}%'.format(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)))" | python3
9.5%

real    0m2.127s
user    0m0.119s
sys 0m0.008s
```

To view the output for **individual cores as well**, let's use this python program below. First, I obtain a python list (array) of "per CPU" information, then I average everything in that list to get a "total % CPU" type value. Then I print the total and the individual core percents.

Python program:

```py
import psutil

cpu_percent_cores = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2, percpu=True)
avg = sum(cpu_percent_cores)/len(cpu_percent_cores)
cpu_percent_total_str = ('%.2f' % avg) + '%'
cpu_percent_cores_str = [('%.2f' % x) + '%' for x in cpu_percent_cores]
print('Total: {}'.format(cpu_percent_total_str))
print('Individual CPUs: {}'.format('  '.join(cpu_percent_cores_str)))
```

This can be wrapped up into an incredibly ugly 1-line bash script like this if you like. I had to be sure to use only single quotes (`''`), NOT double quotes (`""`) in the Python program in order to make this wrapping into a bash 1-liner work:

```bsh
printf "%b" "import psutil\n\
cpu_percent_cores = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2, percpu=True)\n\
avg = sum(cpu_percent_cores)/len(cpu_percent_cores)\n\
cpu_percent_total_str = ('%.2f' % avg) + '%'\n\
cpu_percent_cores_str = [('%.2f' % x) + '%' for x in cpu_percent_cores]\n\
print('Total: {}'.format(cpu_percent_total_str))\n\
print('Individual CPUs: {}'.format('  '.join(cpu_percent_cores_str)))\n\
" | python3
```

Sample output: notice that I have 8 cores, so there are 8 numbers after "Individual CPUs:":

```
Total: 10.15%
Individual CPUs: 11.00%  8.50%  11.90%  8.50%  9.90%  7.60%  11.50%  12.30%
```

For **more information on how the `psutil.cpu_percent(interval=2)` python call works**, see the [official `psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None, percpu=False)` documentation here](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_percent):

> `psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None, percpu=False)`
>
> Return a float representing the current system-wide CPU utilization as a percentage. When interval is > `0.0` compares system CPU times elapsed before and after the interval (blocking). When interval is `0.0` or `None` compares system CPU times elapsed since last call or module import, returning immediately. That means the first time this is called it will return a meaningless `0.0` value which you are supposed to ignore. In this case it is recommended for accuracy that this function be called with at least `0.1` seconds between calls. When percpu is True returns a list of floats representing the utilization as a percentage for each CPU. First element of the list refers to first CPU, second element to second CPU and so on. The order of the list is consistent across calls.
>
> **Warning:** the first time this function is called with interval = `0.0` or `None` it will return a meaningless `0.0` value which you are supposed to ignore.

### References:

1. [Stack Overflow: How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468983/4561887)
2. [Stack Overflow: Executing multi-line statements in the one-line command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043453/executing-multi-line-statements-in-the-one-line-command-line/29565580#29565580)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149006/how-to-display-a-float-with-two-decimal-places
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039961/finding-the-average-of-a-list/9040000#9040000